# Why not ship with all trusted PPA's installed?

Tags: apt, ppa, repository

I was searching for a PPA to install some software, and as I was finding all of these repositories, I was thinking: Why not ship Ubuntu with all of the trusted PPA's already installed, like webupd8 and Ubuntu-x-swat? Are they not really secure, or is there another reason? It sure would save me a lot of time if I didn't have to search google for repositories with my software. Thanks!

PS: I can't find a tag for a question that concern choices made by the Ubuntu team. Can someone make one?

Comment: Because those repositories are not created or maintained by ubuntu. 
What software do you have to find? Ubuntu repos have almost 100,000 packages per version.

Comment: I've never heard of the "webupd8" PPA and I have no idea who makes it. As far as I'm concerned, it's not "trusted".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Ubuntu isn't a rolling release.

Ubuntu's software update policy is to pick set versions for all its packages and then to maintain those packages, backporting security fixes as applicable. This means most software on a Long Term Support release will function *the same way* for five years. That's a major feature in industry.

This wouldn't be the case if they all just tracked the latest versions. There are limited exceptions to this (eg Firefox) but they aren't important to this topic.

PPAs exist for a number of reasons but the ones you're talking about are to get bleeding edge software to people. Usually for testing that software, but occasionally —especially with graphics, wifi, etc— to update driver stacks to improve functionality.

These bleeding edge software stacks are not suitable for everybody. They have downsides. They aren't supported. They occasionally brake things for user. They frequently push major version changes (and with it major feature changes) for software. That's great if you want to opt into that, less so if you want a stable software base for 5 years.

I've nothing against WebUpd8 but I'm sure even they wouldn't consider themselves comparable to the teams of maintainers and security teams who look after Ubuntu's packages. It's not just about trusting people's intent, it's also making sure they have the technical mechanisms and ability to stop bad software getting on your computer.

But putting "trust" aside, if you did ship Ubuntu with these PPAs "already installed", it'd make Ubuntu partially a rolling release. That isn't what Ubuntu is, or wants to be.

Comment: +1: It's not just about trusting people's intent, it's also making sure they have the technical mechanisms and ability...